# How to nest percent symbol in .xml config

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, dtd

Suppose I am trying to write some lines of code inside a .XML file (within the context of .dtd structures where settings and vars are being parsed and outputted into configuration files.)

```
% If ... %
% then replace(%var%, something_else) %
```

The problem with this, is that I not only need to use the percent sign to tell the .XML parser that these blocks should be parsed into its respective coding language, but the %var% is being used to represent the value of an variable, which the given XML parser is not happy about.

Currently getting this error - `Unexpected end of directive`. This is caused by the parser cutting off the statement at the second **%** occurrence. Turning the second line of code into -

`% then replace(%`.

Are there any workarounds to tell the parser that it should keep scanning till the last **%** shows up before giving up the line?

Comment: In XML (outside the DTD) `%` characters are ordinary characters, they have no special meaning to the parser. You mention DTD in your tags, but not in your question, so I don't know if this is relevant. Anyway, it looks to me as if this problem is not at the XML level, but at the level of whatever application is using the XML, which you haven't identified.

Comment: @MichaelKay apologies, yes this is within the context of .dtd files.